# Why we require Apache Kafka with NoSQL databases?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, apache-kafka

Apache Kafka is an real-time messaging service. It stores streams of data safely in distributed and fault-tolerant. We can filter streaming data when comming producer. I don't understant that why we need NoSQL databases like as MongoDB to store same data in Apache Kafka. The true question is that why we store same data in a NoSQL database and Apache Kafka?

I think if we need a NoSQL database, we can collect streams of data from clients in MongoDB at first without the use of Apache Kafka. But, most of big data architecture preference using Apache Kafka between data source and NoSQL database.([see](https://techbeacon.com/what-apache-kafka-why-it-so-popular-should-you-use-it))
[image: and also see]

What is the advantages of that for real systems?

Comment: So the answer is we do not require Kafka with NoSQL DBs; reversely, we require NoSQL DBs with Kafka for buffering and adding Fault-tolerance to our NoSQL DB.

Comment: This is the answer I actually wanted to hear. Thank you, @mostafa.S.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This architecture has several advantages:

1. **Kafka as Data Integration Bus**

   It helps distribute data between several producers and many consumers easily. Here Apache Kafka serves as an "data" integration message bus.
2. **Kafka as Data Buffer**

   Putting Kafka in front of your "end" data storages like MongoDB or MySQL acts like a natural data buffer. So you are able to deploy/maintain/redeploy your consumer services independently. At the time your service is down for maintanance Kafka is still storing all incoming data, that is quite useful.
3. **Kafka as a Short Time Data Storage**

   You don't have to store everything in Kafka: very often you use Kafka topics with retention. It means all data older than some value will be deleted by Kafka automatically. So, for example you may have Kafka topic with 1 week retention (so you store 1 week of data only) but at the same time your data lives in long time storage services like classic SQL-DBs or Cassandra etc.
4. **Kafka as a Long Time Data Storage**

   On the other hand you can use Apache Kafka as a long term storage system. Using compacted topics enables you to store only the last value for each key. So your topic becomes a last state storage of your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for understandable answer. **Kafka as Data Integration Bus** can be really useful. I got **Kafka as Data Buffer**. This property reduces risk of data loss. When system live, Apache Kafka can be down and data is lost.  But unfortunatelly, still I didn't understant why we choice **Kafka as a Long Time Data Storage**. Because, If we use Apache Kafka as a long time data storage, we don't need another storage system.

Comment: @tolgabuyuktanir every storage system should be used for data it designed for (message data, document, relational, you name it). I mean, you can use Kafka as a long term storage, but it totally depends on your use case.

For example, storing state snapshots to Kafka from your app is totally ok. Every time your app is up, it reads the last snapshot. But using Kafka for quering data (for example) is very inefficient. In this case you can export data from kafka to some system which allows querying.

Comment: Thank you @leshkin. I understood what you say and ı got it. Thanks for your patience and answer.

Comment: I'd add one more point: *5. Kafka as a stream processing layer* You can use this to filter/enrich/aggregate data as it flows through, thus optimising and simplifying many designs.