# Apache Kafka for an existing get request with Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I’m trying to learn about streaming services and reading `kafka` doc’s :

https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

https://kafka.apache.org/24/documentation/streams/quickstart

To take a simple example I’m attempting to refactor a Spring web services GET request which accepts an ID parameter and returns a list of attributes associated with that ID. The DB backend is Oracle.

What is the approach for loading a single Oracle DB table which can be served by Kafka ? The above docs don't contain information for this. Do I need to replicate the Oracle DB to a NoSql DB such as MongoDB ? ([Why we require Apache Kafka with NoSQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48742935/why-we-require-apache-kafka-with-nosql-databases))

Comment: @mazaneicha I did mean Oracle. The service I'm attempting to refactor reads from an Oracle DB.

Comment: @mazaneicha your right, my apologies, I've updated that sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka is an event streaming platform. It is not a database. Instead of thinking about "loading a single Oracle DB table which can be served by Kafka", you need to think in terms of what events are you looking for that will trigger processing?

Change Data Capture (CDC) products like Oracle Golden Gate (there are other products too) will detect changes to rows and send messages into Kafka each time a row changes.

Alternatively you could configure a Kafka JDBC Source Connector to execute a query and pull data into Kafka.